# Delphi to Java (biometrics)

Tags: java, pointers, structure, jna, biometrics

I'm developing a tool for recognition biometric and I'm using the provided SDK (*.dll), developed in Delphi.

For the access at dll, I'm using JNA.

The template of the digital (the most important part) is an object  which refers to this passage(in Delphi):

```
    type
    CIS_Digital = packed record
      intSize: integer;
      pDigital: Pointer
    end;
  pCIS_Digital = ^CIS_Digital;
```

How to develop something equivalent in Java?

Thanks.

Comment: Id suggest writing a wrapper in C that exposes your Delphi functions to Java. Then call the wrapper.

Comment: You don't show research, and this seems too localized. Please show some effort

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the following call DLL functions:

SDK_CIS_Iniciar(int cnpj, int detectaFake);

SDK_CIS_LerDigital(pCIS_Digital digital);

SDK_CIS_CompararDigital(pCIS_Digital sample1, pCIS_Digital sample2);

SDK_CIS_Finalizar ();

Looking at the **example provided, developed in Delphi**, I saw that the pCIS_Digital object, which is passed on SDK_CIS_LerDigital () and SDK_CIS_CompararDigital () references the code snippet:

```
type
    CIS_Digital = packed record
      intSize: integer;
      pDigital: Pointer
    end;
  pCIS_Digital = ^CIS_Digital;
```

In the example developed in Delphi, before calling the SDK_CIS_LerDigital () method, the pCIS_Digital object is instantiated.

That is, it (the object parameter) will emptiness and is "filled" by function.

The reader is TechMag BioFlex (http://www.techmag.com.br/bioflex/), which is based on Futronic readers (SF-80).

Searching, I saw that the pCIS_Digital object (code snippet), makes memory access to read the information that the reader writes it writes.

After much research, I **think** I should develop an equivalent object in Java, extending the **Structure** or **Memory** class, of the JNA.